# Link for Jeffs VS Color Theme?

Tags: visual-studio-2008, colors, themes

http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/files/exported-font-and-colors-for-jeff-atwood-sept-19.zip

The Link is not working, 
anybody has a mirror, or an export for VS 2008?

Answer (score 9):

<s>I've uploaded the zip file to Drop.io</s>.

On a side note: Scott Hanselman has a [blog post](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/VisualStudioProgrammerThemesGallery.aspx) in which he talks about some Visual Studio themes, worth a look!

---

**EDIT**: 21 Jan 2011 
Drop.io discontinued it's service since it's been bought by Facebook. 
I've uploaded the zip to my skydrive instead:

https://skydrive.live.com/?cid=07d66fa40734f332&sc=documents&id=7D66FA40734F332!833 (may require login)

Thanks for pointing that out, Will!

Comment: Since a week there is a website called "Studio Styles" which hosts 2008 and 2010 themes for Visual Studio: http://studiostyles.info/
Worth a look imo!

Answer (score 0):

This should be valid for a while.
Choose save as and there you go.

http://dl.dropbox.com/u/8430002/exported-font-and-colors-for-jeff-atwood.vssettings